# Inheritance from immutable type, attribute access

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a class which inherits the `str`:

```
class UpperStr(str):

    def __new__(cls, value, font_size=12):
        print 'In redefined new...'
        return str.__new__(cls, value.upper())

    def __init__(self, value, font_size=12):
        print 'In init...'
        self.font_size = font_size
```

Then I can access an attribute defined in derived class:

```
s = UpperStr('hello')
print s.font_size
```

But since there's no way to get an instance of base class from the instance of derived class in python, how can I get the value of `str` itself (`'hello'` in this case)?

Comment: `s` or `self` is `'hello'` here. `s` is basically an instance of `str` as well.

Comment: but inheritance in python assumes that your derived class will have the same attributes and methods as based + additional methods and attributes defined in derived class itself. `s` is not an instance of `str` in that sense. What's the logical explanation?

Comment: `isinstance(s, str)`... looks like `s` is a `str` to me!

Answer (score 1):

Use `self` to refer to the string itself.